# Launch one project's executable from another project's executable

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio

I have a solution with 6 projects -- four are WPF apps and two are shared model and data access libraries.  Normally the WPF apps are run independently.  However, I want to add a button to one WPF app that launches one of the other WPF apps.

What code would I need to add to my first WPF app's view model to launch the executable of the second app?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You either add reference to the assembly of the project you want to start. This way you can simply create an instance and do .show()

The other way would be with Process.Start() and put the path of your executable to run it

**EDIT:** On the project that wish to open other project: right click References-> Add references -> Solution -> check the project you want to create -> OK

You might need to add extra references if the compiler ask you to (PresentationFramework, system.xaml ...)

And then

```
 private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    WpfApplication1.MainWindow mw = new WpfApplication1.MainWindow();
    mw.Show();
}
```

Just change WpfApplication1 to the project's assembly name and MainWindow by the name of the windows you want to call on that assembly

Comment: Can you show an example of creating an instance and then using the Show() method?

Comment: There we go :) Just adjust your the Assembly called and the Name of the window that i called and it should work

Answer (score 3):

You can use `Process.Start("path/to/your/file")` and put the path to the `.exe` of your other project in it.